# What Statistics Framework / Tools use with data from different sources

Tags: datasource, statistics

I got many datasources (postgres database, logfiles) containing statistic data or containing data from which you can calculate statistic data.

Im searching for a application where you can design new reports / outputs (graphs, tables etc) without using a programing language but using a gui. You should be able to save these queries and rerun them later. A webaplication (or a webservice) would be better than a offline app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No programming language? Well that takes out most of the market and even some of the tools mentioned (excel etc) are going to require some VBA to get them to preform like you would expect.

If you have some funds, I would suggest looking into SAS EGuide. It is a point and click, Gui interface that allows you to pull in data from ANYWHERE and manipulate in the interface. The "projects" as they are called can be saved and reused.

My best recommendation would be to use an agency partner with experience in this type of reporting / analytics. I work for such a company. Keep us in mind if we can help. (http://www.AFHood.com)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [R (link)](http://www.r-project.org/) (a free version of [S or S-Plus](http://www.insightful.com/)), or [SPSS](http://www.spss.com/) 
. And don't leave out good old Excel (or the free clones like Open Office). When combined with the "get external data" options this can do a surprising amount without much code.

There are others which are more specific to certain domains, eg finance.

However, almost any stats is data dependent enough you'll need some sort of programming/scripting language. The pure visual solutions often don't end up doing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across an online data visualization site, [Verifiable](http://www.verifiable.com) - haven't used it but from the screencast on the opening page it seems to have some useful summary stats.

If your data is not confidential, it might be worth a try...

A couple of expensive, but slick products are:

- [Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/Products/Info.aspx) (advanced data analysis)
- [Advizor](http://www.visualinsights.com/products.htm) (business intelligence).